# Email Validation Function from a different class seems to return the wrong value

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem with the Prestashop core code that seems to ruin my day, I'm obviously missing something trivial for the last few hours. So here is the deal:

I have a class method that will validate fields from all kinds of form. In my case, it's all about a customer form with an email which is always reported as being invalid format.

It will call for a different method ($constraint) from a different class (Validate) for each field to check if everything is ok with that field.

Since my issue is with checking the email format I added these lines to it before it runs the check so I can have an output to warn me if it will work or not:

```
if ($constraint=='isEmail') 
{
    print 'Check for validating '.PHP_EOL;
    print Validate::$constraint($field->getValue())?'is valid ':'not valid '.PHP_EOL;
}
```

I also added another line in the section that would only get triggered if a field will fail validation:

```
if ($constraint=='isEmail') 
{
    print 'failed '.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here is the full method as it stands right now:

```
abstract class AbstractFormCore implements FormInterface
{
    public function validate()
    {
        foreach ($this->formFields as $field) {
            if ($field->isRequired() && !$field->getValue()) {
                $field->addError(
                    $this->constraintTranslator->translate('required')
                );
                continue;
            } elseif (!$field->isRequired() && !$field->getValue()) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($field->getConstraints() as $constraint) {
                if ($constraint=='isEmail') 
                {
                    print 'Check for validating '.PHP_EOL;
                    print Validate::$constraint($field->getValue())?'is valid ':'not valid '.PHP_EOL;
                }
                if (!Validate::$constraint($field->getValue())) {
                    if ($constraint=='isEmail') 
                    {
                        print 'failed '.PHP_EOL;
                    }
                    $field->addError(
                        $this->constraintTranslator->translate($constraint)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        exit;
        return !$this->hasErrors();
    }
}
```

As for the contraint function, here is it's source:

```
class ValidateCore
{
    public static function isEmail($email)
    {
        print 'validating '.$email.' '.PHP_EOL;
        return true;
        return (!empty($email) && preg_match(Tools::cleanNonUnicodeSupport('/^[a-z\p{L}0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^`{}|~_-]+[.a-z\p{L}0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^`{}|~_-]*@[a-z\p{L}0-9]+(?:[.]?[_a-z\p{L}0-9-])*\.[a-z\p{L}0-9]+$/ui'), $email));
    }
}
```

You'll notice that I changed it adding an output line and also having it return true regardless of the parameter.

So with this setup, when the script is validating an email, I'd expect following output:

"Check for validating" (triggered by the Validate() function because it has reached a field with the isEmail constraint the first time) 
"validating email@email.com" (triggered by isEmail function to let me know that that function is being ran) 
"is valid" (triggered by the Validate() function because the isEmail() function always returns true) 
"validating email@email.com" (triggered by isEmail that is being ran the second time by Validate())

Instead I get the following output

> validating email@email.com 
>   Check for validating  
>   validating email@email.com  
>   not valid  
>   validating email@email.com  
>   failed

So I the isEmail() function gets triggered once before but I don't think that's relevant. 
Then the "Check for validating" is obviously sent to the output as expected. 
I then get the "validating ..." message to let me know that isEmail was triggered. 
And then, for some reason the  *Validate::$constraint($field->getValue())?'is valid ':'not valid '.PHP_EOL*  line will output "not valid".
I then get the "failed" output which is no surprise.

I simply can't understand how that line will output "not valid" since I made sure that the constraint function isEmail() will always return true.

I apologize if I haven't been clear enough, my head is already spinning from this. I feel like there is something very obvious I'm missing but I simply can't realise what that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Update: It seems the issue was entirely somewhere else. Someone else had overwritten the "isEmail" function using the inbuild Prestashop overwrite engine and it's behaviour was entirely different.